# How to patch wireless driver rtl8187 for 2.6.30 kernels?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, wifi, patch

I am using Backtrack 4 (installed on hdd), and I have an USB wifi adapter that uses rtl8187.

I am trying to test wep cracking on my router (the signal is about 80%).

I executed aireplay -9 and it shows "Injection is working 30/30 100%". But when start airodump to capture ivs, and aireplay -3 to inject, it only captures 1 iv every few seconds.

On aircrack website I found http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=rtl8187, but it seems those patches are for an old kernel, so I went here http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/ and there i see:

rtl8187-mac80211-injection-speed-2.6.30-rc3.patch

This looks appropriated for BT4, but I don't know how to apply the patch.

**Could someone explain me how?** (preferably without having to recompile kernels)

And is there any other patch I should apply on bt4 (2.6.30)?

Comment: A kernel patch is for source code, so you have no real choice but to recompile *something*.

Comment: Isn't is possible to use something like compat-wireless?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [backports](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (previously known as compat-wireless)

This package contains sources of the latest wireless drivers and patches and scripts
which allows you to build the latest driver but targeted at an old kernel (i.e. your currently installed one). It could be that using the latest driver would be enough to solve your problem and if not you should apply your patch to the driver source under backports.